# DB table design for attributes with multiple entries (eg: Person -> Social Media)

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to decide the structure of a DB table to store Employee data. I am bit confused on how to design attributes such as Address, Social Media etc. There should be provision for multiple Social Media entries (eg: Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn etc) for a single employee record.

Which one would be a good design :

1. Creating a separate table for Social Media (with type and URL/hanlde)
   OR
2. Create few repeating fields within employee table itself to store social media data. (eg: fb_url, twtr_handle, ln_url)

Would it be an overkill to create a separate tables for these kind of attributes? Attribute "Social media" is just an example, we will have many attributes in the employee table that would have 1 to 4 entries (eg: Phone Numbers, Addresses, Email Addresses)

Thanks

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hello. This isn't exactly the faster solution, as you would have to value all the pros & cons, but you could try with a nosql database such ad mongodb. That'd allow you to use a flexible schema

Comment: Why would you want a nosql solution here? A flexible schema most likely not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In a NoSQL DataBase I'd go with the option 2.
In a relational schema I think the option 1 is better. If you want to add a new social media (Instagram f.i.) it will be just another entry in the social media table. But if you add the social media in Person you will need to add a new column in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions will work.

The main downside in NOT creating a separate table for SocialMedia info is the need to add new column in `Employee` table for every new social media type that there will be in the future. It's usually a bit pain-in-the-ass to make changes to the DB schema when an application is already in production.

So, keeping that in mind, I'd recommend to create a separate SocialMedia table which will have this structure:

```
| SocialMedia | username | employeeId |
```

where `employeeId` column will be the foreign key to `Employee` table